Проблема с установкой pyqt-tools
Пробовал установить PyQt5 и PyQt6, в результате сам pyqt в обоих случаях устанавливается нормально, а pyqt-tools(что 5, что 6) выдаёт ошибку metadata-generation-failed. Версия Python 3.12.3, в интернете нашёл только то, что нужна последняя версия Python(у меня именно она), и что PyQt5 не совместим с M1 на Mac(я пытался установить как пятый, так и шестой, да и плюс у меня ноут на винде и Intel))
Сама ошибка:
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      pyproject.toml: line 7: using '[tool.sip.metadata]' to specify the project metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '[project]' instead
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel        
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 92, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 587, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9w45o5_u\pyqt6_13c3263a185a4827a4df706f02c146f6\project.py", line 60, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 51, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 50, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

